# Scroll back to top on BottomNavigationBar - flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, bottomnavigationview

I am making an app that has a `BottomNavigationBar` with 3 items, the first one is the Home page and it contains a `ListView` of items.
What i want to do is make the ListView scroll back to top when the Home button in the BottomNavigationBar is pressed.
Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score -1):

1. initiate ScrollController for ListView
2. use onTap from BottomNavigationBar and get the current index
3. in onTap func, determine index == 0 and scrollController.jumpTo(0.0);